# PL SQL UTL_HTTP Restful web service call not working

Tags: encoding, plsql, oracle11g, character-encoding, encode

I have created a procedure which calls a restful web service from Oracle 11.2 server using UTL_HTTP package. It's a post request and I send an arabic value along with other data which defined as varchar2.

Arabic string is sent as "???? ????", to web service which I checked in the logging. I set the body as UTF-8 and database server character set is "AR8ISO8859P6".

I tried with convert function and all the ways possible. I could not figure out how to fix it.

Find below code.

```
  t_request_body :=
         '{
 "ArabicValue":"'
      || p_arabic_value
      || '",
 "EnglishValue":"'
      || p_english_value
      || '"
}';

   UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout (5);
   t_http_req :=
      UTL_HTTP.begin_request
         ('webservice_url',
          'POST',
          'HTTP/1.1'
         );
   /*Describe in the request-header*/
   UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (t_http_req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (t_http_req, 'Content-Length', LENGTH (t_request_body));
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (t_http_req, 'TransactionId', t_transaction_id);
   UTL_HTTP.set_header (t_http_req, 'Accept', 'application/xml');

   /*Put the data in de body of the request*/
   UTL_HTTP.write_text (t_http_req, t_request_body);
/*Web service call*/
   t_http_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response (t_http_req);
/*Reading transaction id from header*/
   UTL_HTTP.get_header_by_name (t_http_resp, 'TransactionId', t_trans);
```

English value parameter is passing to web service fine. Arabic value is going as "????? ????". I tried convert function available in oracle to convert it to UTF-8. It's not working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following :

length_bytes := length(utl_raw.convert(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t_request_body), 'AL32UTF8', 'AR8ISO8859P6'));

UTL_HTTP.set_header (t_http_req, 'Content-Length', length_bytes);

UTL_HTTP.write_raw (t_http_req, t_request_body);